# Is there a way to expose Mezzanine Keywords on the admin pages?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm trying to allow Keywords to be edited sitewide, this is what i did try so far:

```
ADMIN_MENU_ORDER = (
     ("Content", ("pages.Page",   
                  "blog.BlogPost",
                  "generic.ThreadedComment",
                  "generic.Keyword",
                  ("Media Library", "fb_browse"),
     )),
     ("Users", ("auth.User",
                "auth.Group",
     )),
     ("Site", ("sites.Site",
               "redirects.Redirect",
               "conf.Setting",
     )),
 )
```

But there is just no "Keywords" section appearing where i could easily edit the Keywords i did set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Django admin class for the Keyword model and register it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: This wasn't necessary for comments, was it?

Comment: No comments already has an admin class built and registered by default. The expectation is that it's needed to manage the comments, whereas the keywords are generally managed via whatever they're assigned to.